# How to set canvas attributes from P5.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, p5.js

I am using P5.js (https://p5js.org/) for an application where I need multiple off-screen canvases.  This is working just fine.  Each canvas is created within a class as follows:

```
this.canvas = createGraphics(w, h);
```

In an attempt to experiment with performance, I decided it might be interesting to set `willReadFrequently` to `true`:

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#concept-canvas-will-read-frequently

This, in response to a warning I got:

```
Canvas2D: Multiple readback operations using getImageData are faster
with the willReadFrequently attribute set to true.
```

I can read the canvas attributes just fine using:

```
console.log(this.canvas.drawingContext.getContextAttributes());
```

The result is:

```
alpha: true
colorSpace: "srgb"
desynchronized: false
willReadFrequently: "undefined"
```

However, I can't seem to come-up with a way to set this attribute.  P5.js does have a `setAttributes()` method:

https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/setAttributes

When I try to use it, like this, I get a `setAttributes is not a function` or `Cannot read proproties of undefined` error:

```
this.canvas.drawingContext.setAttributes("willReadFrequently", true);
// or
this.canvas.setAttributes("willReadFrequently", true);
// or
this.canvas.setAttributes[{"willReadFrequently": true}];
```

These two attempts (tried all lower case as well) result in `Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'willReadFrequently')`:

```
this.canvas.drawingContext.setAttributes.willReadFrequently = true;
this.canvas.drawingContext.setAttributes["willReadFrequently"] = true;
```

This attempt did not generate any errors, yet `getContextAttributes()` shows that nothing changed:

```
this.canvas.drawingContext.willReadFrequently = true;
```

Finally, looking at the **Canvas API** documentation...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext

I thought I should be able to do something like this:

```
this.canvas.drawingContext({willReadFrequently:true});
```

Once again, the error is `is not a function`.

I'm pretty sure I am missing something very fundamental here.  I don't have the freedom to completely abandon P5 for the entire application.  Do I need to rewrite this class to use the raw **Canvas API** for this to work?  That's a lot of work.  I wanted to get a sense of potential performance improvement before doing something like that.

Answer (score 2):

The `willReadFrequently` attribute of a `CanvasRenderingContext2D` isn't modifiable once the context has been created.
Instead it's an option passed to the `.getContext()` method.

e.g.

```
let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d", {
    willReadFrequently: true
});
```

### Edit

If we look up the function definiton for p5.js's `createGraphics()` method at https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/main/src/core/rendering.js, we can see it's doing this:

```
p5.prototype.createGraphics = function(w, h, renderer) {
  p5._validateParameters('createGraphics', arguments);
  return new p5.Graphics(w, h, renderer, this);
};
```

So it's returning a new `Graphics` instance. Inside the class definition at
https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/main/src/core/p5.Graphics.js we can see it's instantiating a Rendered2D object

```
this._renderer = new p5.Renderer2D(this.canvas, this, false);
```

The constructor of this class is responsible for creating the 2D context. All we have to do is enhancing the constructor with the `willReadFrequently` attribute.

Suppose we are using a CDN hosted version of p5.js, we can trace the current constructor function like:

```js
console.log(p5.Renderer2D);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.min.js" integrity="sha512-3RlxD1bW34eFKPwj9gUXEWtdSMC59QqIqHnD8O/NoTwSJhgxRizdcFVQhUMFyTp5RwLTDL0Lbcqtl8b7bFAzog==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

and override it like:

```js
p5.Renderer2D = function(e, t, r) {
  return d.default.Renderer.call(this, e, t, r), this.drawingContext = this.canvas.getContext("2d", {
    willReadFrequently: true
  }), this._pInst._setProperty("drawingContext", this.drawingContext), this
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.min.js" integrity="sha512-3RlxD1bW34eFKPwj9gUXEWtdSMC59QqIqHnD8O/NoTwSJhgxRizdcFVQhUMFyTp5RwLTDL0Lbcqtl8b7bFAzog==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Right.  Please note I am not doing what your code does.  I am creating off-screen canvases using this p5.js function:  https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createGraphics

It looks like I might need to dig into p5's source to understand what they might be doing before I can understand how to set this attribute.

Comment: Thanks.  I experimented with this a bit before you posted this.  The only reliable way I found to do this was to edit the file and end-up with a custom p5.js local import (which I could minify if needed).  Attempts to override seemed to run into issues.  I can't run a full regression test on p5.js, which makes either the direct edit or override hacks potentially undesirable.  I'll continue to experiment and report back.

There's also this, where someone points out there might be issues when setting this property to true:

https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/5840